# How to block search queries less then 3

Tags: php

I'm making a search function for my website, but I want to block searches that are less then 3 characters

```
if($search > 3){
    header('Location: error.txt');
}
```

its probably something very simple. please help

Comment: you can block using jquery on client side.Before submit check if search length is less than three then don't submit form.

Comment: @Gaurav do it in both front and backend to make sure, not just jquery, just get the string length

Comment: @Ghost yes, I agree with you. I because someone already answered so that why didn't write that on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `strlen()` to get the characters count.

```
 if(strlen($search) < 3){
   header('Location: error.txt');
}
```